# Directions API is not working on a physical device

Tags: xamarin.android, httprequest, google-directions-api

I write an app on Xamarin.Android. Directions API works perfectly when debugging on emulator. But it doesn't work when testing on a physical device. I suppose the problem can be in http request. Is somebody familiar with such a problem?

```
public async Task<string> GetDirectionJsonAsync(LatLng location, LatLng destLocation, string mapkey)
{
    // Origin of route
    string str_origin = "origin=" + location.Latitude.ToString() + "," + location.Longitude.ToString();

    // Destination of route
    string str_destination = "destination=" + destLocation.Latitude.ToString() + "," + destLocation.Longitude.ToString();

    // Mode
    string mode = "mode=driving";

    string parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_destination + "&" + mode + "&key=" + mapkey;

    // Output
    string output = "json";

    string url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    string jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    return jsonString;
}
```

Comment: According to your description, yousaid that you project works perfectly when debuging on emulator, but have some problem when run on Android device? What is Android device version? Without internet question?

Comment: Is there any error messages you get from the actual device?